# How can I reshape a wide CSV table using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This question is about reshaping data from a CSV file using Python. I have a CSV file containing a wide table of values. Each row represents an organization and each column contains the value of a different variable.

How can I reshape this data so that each row represents a tuple of (date, orgID, variable, value):

**Original shape:**

| Date | Org ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/30/2022 | 04815 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 30 |
| 6/30/2022 | 01712 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 14 |

**Desired shape:**

| Date | Org ID | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/30/2022 | 04815 | A | 10 |
| 6/30/2022 | 04815 | B | 15 |
| 6/30/2022 | 04815 | C | 20 |
| 6/30/2022 | 04815 | D | 30 |
| 6/30/2022 | 01712 | A | 4 |
| 6/30/2022 | 01712 | B | 8 |
| 6/30/2022 | 01712 | C | 9 |
| 6/30/2022 | 01712 | D | 14 |

Comment: Have you tried [df.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt)? E.g. `df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Org ID'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `melt`:

```
res = df.melt(id_vars=['Date','Org ID'])
```

output :

```
        Date  Org ID variable  value
0  6/30/2022    4815        A     10
1  6/30/2022    1712        A      4
2  6/30/2022    4815        B     15
3  6/30/2022    1712        B      8
4  6/30/2022    4815        C     20
5  6/30/2022    1712        C      9
6  6/30/2022    4815        D     30
7  6/30/2022    1712        D     14
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) then use [`pandas.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on `column='Org ID'` by `ascending=False`.

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date', 'Org ID']).sort_values('Org ID', ascending=False)
print(df)
```

---

```
        Date  Org ID variable  value
0  6/30/2022    4815        A     10
2  6/30/2022    4815        B     15
4  6/30/2022    4815        C     20
6  6/30/2022    4815        D     30
1  6/30/2022    1712        A      4
3  6/30/2022    1712        B      8
5  6/30/2022    1712        C      9
7  6/30/2022    1712        D     14
```